# Change the generated EDIT routes in Rails 3.2 to put id _after_ `edit`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

As well explained in the [Rails Guide on Routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html), a resourceful route declaration like

```
resources :photos
```

generates a suite of routes and helpers.  One of the routes is

```
/photos/:id/edit
```

and along with it comes the helper `edit_photo_path(photo)` which takes a `photo` object and returns the path to use to edit it.  **I use the helpers everywhere and want them to keep working as-is**.

Well, for various reasons, this one application is generating custom IDs and it is possible for an ID to look like `64/edit` or look like `64`.  This of course causes problems, because regardless of constraints or tweaks

```
/photos/64/edit
```

either gets interpreted as `#edit 64` or `#show 64/edit` and neither one is always right.

The solution I would like to implement is to keep all the benefits of resourceful routers, in including being able to pass objects into the path helpers, and just change the Rails default edit path to be

```
/photos/edit/:id
```

Then all the paths would be unambiguous.  Is there a (reasonably simple and clean) way to do this?

#### Note

- I have a workaround in place so please do not provide workarounds.
- Any solution must update the helpers so that `edit_photo_path(photo)` produces `/photos/edit/:id` and also works with nested resources.  For example, `edit_magazine_photo_path(@magazine, @photo)` would produce `/magazines/:magazine_id/photos/edit/:id`.
- I have multiple resources, so I'd prefer not to explode the size of my routes.rb with special overrides.
- I know I can change the path name of the `edit` portion using the `path_names` option.  (This is, in fact what I did, putting a Unicode character that will never appear in the ID in the renamed edit path, but now I have the users seeing Unicode URLs, which I don't like, and this will fail once IDs get expanded to Unicode strings.)
- I know I can write custom `match` rules, but that gets very tedious and difficult with nested resources, particularly when it comes to generating path helpers that take objects.
- I read the answer to the question "Remove the edit suffix to url" but that answer does not, in fact, remove the edit suffix, it changes a different part of the URL.
- I really want insight into the inner workings of the resourceful route generation, especially the URL helpers, so that I can just switch the order of `edit` and `id` in the path.

Comment: "Is there a (reasonably simple and clean) way to do this?" > no.